# What does it mean to find three different sets of basis for its range?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

I have a matrix $A$.

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0.5 & 0 & -0.5 & 3\\
        -0.5 & 3 & -2.5 & -3\\
        -0.5 & 2 & -1.5 & -3\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Row Reduces to
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
        0 & 1 & -1 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Which means there are $3$ pivots and rank = $3$.

The range($A$) is the span of columns $1,2,4$. What does it mean find three different sets of basis for its range? Am I looking to find the null space of the three vectors in the range of $A$?